# Find regex matches & remove outer part of the match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a string

```
content = "std::cout << func(some_val) << std::endl; auto i = func(some_other_val);"
```

and I find to find all instances with `func(...)`, and remove the function call. So that I would get

```
content = "std::cout << some_val << std::endl; auto i = some_other_val;"
```

So I've tried this:

```py
import re
content = "std::cout << func(some_val) << std::endl; auto i = func(some_other_val);"
c       = re.compile('func\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\)')

print(c.sub('', content))           # gives "std::cout <<  << std::endl; auto i = ;"
```

but this removes the entire match, not just the `func(` and `)`.

Basically, how do I keep whatever matched with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to replace all the outer `func(...)` with only the value like below, See regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/nfFVH7/1)  , Here I've used `[w]+`, you can do changes if you use

```
import re
regex = r"func\(([\w]+)\)"

test_str = "std::cout << func(some_val) << std::endl; auto i = func(some_other_val);"
subst = "\\1"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print (result)
```

**Demo:** https://rextester.com/QZJLF65281

**Output:**

```
std::cout << some_val << std::endl; auto i = some_other_val;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should capture the part of the match that you want to keep into a group:

```
re.compile(r'func\(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)')
```

Here I captured it into group 1.

And then you can refer to group 1 with `\1`:

```
print(c.sub(r'\1', content))
```

Note that in general, you should not use regex to parse source code of a non-regular language (such as C in this case) with regex. It might work in a few very specific cases, where the input is very limited, but you should still use a C parser to parse C code. I have found libraries such as [this](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) and [this](https://github.com/albertz/PyCParser).